# суть глупого многопоточного tcp-сервера

Tags: c++, c, tcp

здравствуйте, обдумываю реализацию многопоточного tcp-сервера... т.е. на одно входящее соединение создается 1 поток(до select/poll я пока не добрался)... предположим, крутится бесконечно в цикле метод accept который возвращает дескриптор нового сокета по которому будет идти взаимодействие каждого нового клиента... и создается новая нить(поток), внутри которой будет какой-то обмен. я думаю это примерно так выглядит:

```
bind();
listen();

while(true) {
    newdescriptor = accept();
    std::thread([=](){
        send();
        receive();
    }).detach();
}
```

я вижу проблему: нету удержания соединения, т.е. сокет новый присылает данные на сервер, сервер отвечает, например, и все, соединение закрывается. как сделать чтобы соединение не закрывалось? и будет ли вообще подход с detach работать? или нужно вообще другую логику использовать для данной модели(поток на соединение)?

Comment: Так не закрывай соединение.

Answer (score 4):

> и все, соединение закрывается

Почему?! TCP соединение закрывается только тогда, когда на обоих  сторонах соединения вызвана функция *close()*. Я не вижу вызова этой ф-ции в Вашем коде.

Внутри цикла *accept* Вы должны только создать нить и передать в неё полученный  от *accept* сокет. А вот внутри нити будет работать **цикл**, внутри которого будет выполняться приём сообщений и отправка ответов. И этот цикл будет крутиться до тех пор, пока обе стороны соединения не придут к соглашению о том, что пора закрывать соединение. Например - клиент передал сообщение *BYE*. Получив это сообщение, нить вызывает *close()* и завершается.

Comment: а detach у нити это норм?

Comment: Судя по синтаксису, Вы пишете эту программу на С++, а на чистом С есть аналог - pthread_detach. Так мне понятнее :-). Ну так этот вызов просто говорит системе о том, что "When a detached thread terminates, its resources are automatically  released  back  to  the  system without the need for another thread to join with the terminated thread." Ну и - на здоровье! Т.е., когда Ваша нить завершится, система автоматически приберёт мусор.  Но нить должна (!!!) завершиться. По некоторому условию, например - приёму сообщения "BYE". Лично я, всё-таки всегда использовал pthread_join().